# Create global variable in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a program which needs user authentication. Now I store the logonname in a Public String, but I want to use more information about the user, like what language he chose to use, his name and stuff like this. I could create another Public String but I don't like that idea.
My goal is to save some data about the user when he enters his username and password.
I want to create something like this:

```
user.logonname
user.language
```

I thought a structure will do the trick, so I created this:

```
Public Structure user
    Public logonname As String
    Public languagetype As String
End Structure
```

But I can only access it like this:

```
Dim user1 as new user
```

But this cannot overwrite the Public Structure, just create an instance of it, therefore other forms won't have the information I need.
I saw something like this in VB6, but that program was using a DLL, containing this type of variable and I don't really understand it and I'm sure there is a better way.
Can someone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why a structure not a class? scope (access) is going to depend on where `user1` is declared though.

Comment: I know I could use classes, but I was hoping there is a variable type or something I could use.

Comment: the issue is not class, structure or variable - it is `scope` - where you declare user1 determines whether it is global, module level, class level or procedure level scope (visibility)

Comment: Oh yeah, now I understand. Thanks man.
If you post it as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Plutonix, I figured it out. If someone needs it, I did it like this:

```
Public Module GeneralModule
    Public Structure user
        Public logonname As String
        Public languagetype As String
    End Structure

    Public guser As New user
End Module
```

And I can access guser anywhere I want.

Example:

```
Private Function login
    'Some other code
    guser.logonname = Me.userid.text
    guser.languagetype = Me.ComboBoxLanguage.Text
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you in your project. Good luck!

```
Public Type EmployeeName

FirstName As String

MidInit As String

LastName As String

End Type



Public Type EmployeeRecord

udtEmpName As EmployeeName

dtmHireDate As Date

sngHourlyRate As Single

dblQuarterlyEarnings(1 To 4) As Double

End Type



Dim udtEmpRec As EmployeeRecord
```

You would reference the EmployeeName fields as follows:

```
udtEmpRec.udtEmpName.FirstName

udtEmpRec.udtEmpName.MidInit

udtEmpRec.udtEmpName.LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a module and declare your public variables in that module. Those variables will be available to the whole project then